# trying to draw Pac-man

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to draw Pac-man as part of an assignment using the convex shape class in SFML and I always get an extra piece drawn from the point 0,0

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
#define PI 3.14f
#define Deg2Rad PI/180
ConvexShape Pac(float radius, Vector2f center)
{
    int pointsCount = 315;
    float theta = 0;
    ConvexShape circle;
    circle.setPointCount(pointsCount);
    for (int i = 45, index = 0; i < 315; i++, index++)
    {
        Vector2f point;
        theta = i * Deg2Rad;
        point.x = center.x + radius * cos(theta);
        point.y = center.y + radius * sin(theta);
        cout << point.x << "," << point.y << endl;
        circle.setPoint(index, point);
    }
    return circle;
}
int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(500, 500), "Pac_man");
    ConvexShape pacman;
    pacman = Pac(100.0f, Vector2f(100, 100));
    pacman.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            }
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(pacman);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it always comes out like this

[image: Pac-man with (0,0) point]

Comment: Can you use this method to render a triangle correctly? Don't compute the corner positions but hardcode them into your sourcecode. If that works, your mistake must be somewhere in between. If not, you have a [mcve]. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop only iterates 270 times (315 - 45), therefore only setting 270 out of 315 vertices. The other 45 vertices are at the default position of (0, 0).

Your next issue is that you do not create a vertex at the center. So you need one extra vertice for the center.

Once those two issues are sorted, the result is:[image: pacman]

**Edit:** I also realise now that Pacman is NOT a convex shape, so "it may not be drawn correctly". To draw it correctly you will need to split it into either multiple convex shapes, or use a different primitive type (sf::TriangleFan?)